# Vector potential in presence of monopole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole, dirac-string

In this paper http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jus/0302/song.pdf when Song was explaining dirac string. He said "In the presence of a magnetic monopole, the vector potential cannot be defined everywhere. Thus, to describe the physics of magnetic monopoles, we must use two vector potentials A1 and A2 which are related by a transformation."

1. Why is it that we must use (at least) 2 vector potentials?
2. And in what way are they related by a transformation? (P. 52 on the right hand side column)[image]

Comment: Comment to the qustion (v2): The first question is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150365/2451

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22967/