# Vector potentials that give monopole magnetic fields with good properties

Tags: magnetic-fields, potential, magnetic-monopoles

I am looking for a vector potential
$$\mathbf{A}=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$$
giving a monopole magnetic field
$$\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{\nabla}\times \mathbf{A}= g\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3} = g \left( \frac{x}{r^3}, \frac{y}{r^3}, \frac{z}{r^3} \right)$$
for which there exist functions $f_x(r)$, $f_y(r)$, and $f_z(r)$ of $r$ satisfying the following equation
$$\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{A} + g\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} = \mathbf{f}(r)=(f_x(r),f_y(r),f_z(r)).$$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

The vector potential is also allowed to be partially singular (or rather, there are no non-singular ones in the entire area).

I'd be grateful if you could give me advice or answers.

Comment: And thus magnetic monopoles do not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know why. @my2cts

Comment: The proof was in the now removed comment: ${\vec \nabla} \cdot {\vec A} =0$ for arbitrary $A$.

Comment: I know that there is no nonsingular vector potential in the entire region. Partially nonsingular vector potentials are also allowed here. Can you prove that they do not exist in such cases? @my2cts

Comment: I should have used the $$\equiv$$ sign. This is a mathematical identity, not to be confused with $$\Delta \phi = 0$ in the absence of sources, which is an Euler-Lagrange equation  of motion, or if you prefer a Maxwell equation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector potential field for a hypothetical magnetic monopole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607264/vector-potential-field-for-a-hypothetical-magnetic-monopole) In particular, my answer on that question explains why you can't define such an $\vec{A}$ on any surface that encloses the monopole.